# Bootstrap modal and ajax content - gallery not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm loading content in bootstrap modal with ajax:

```
$('.open_modal_details').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
     $('#bodyModal').empty();

     $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('home/loadModalData'); ?>", 
        type: "POST",
        data: {product_id: product_id },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#bodyModal').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

In data I'm binding in `#bodyModal` I have some classes which are used by `owlcarousel.js`.

It won't work obviously, DOM doesn't contain data in `#bodyModal` yet.
I tried to load owl library in success function at the end but with no success.

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Do you actually get any data returned from your ajax call? The code 'looks' good. Try console logging the data to make sure that it's actually 'data' that you need and not 'data.data' or 'data.response' for example. Then you'll probably need to re-init the owl carousel after setting the HTML for that body.

Comment: I get all data, that's good. But, in data I have class="owl-carousel" which is used for gallery. Gallery doesn't work!